# Updating a Lambda's Reference Data

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, lambda, malloc

So I've been working on memory management and have a particular issue when it comes to moving objects that contain function objects that wrap lambda's that capture data. Suppose the following example:

```
typedef std::function < void( int ) > funcType;

class Something
{
private:
    int _myNum = 0;

public:
    funcType GetSetIt( )
    {
        return [&] ( int a )
        {
            _myNum = a;
        };
    }

    void SeeIt( )
    {
        std::cout << _myNum << std::endl;
    }

    int GetIt( )
    {
        return _myNum;
    }
};
```

And the following operations:

```
auto destination = ( Something* ) malloc( sizeof( Something ) );
auto alt = ( funcType* ) malloc( sizeof( funcType ) );
auto size = sizeof( funcType );

auto s = new Something( );

auto setIt = s->GetSetIt( );
setIt( 10 );
s->SeeIt( );
auto a = s->GetIt( );

memcpy( destination, s, sizeof( Something ) );
memset(s, 0, sizeof( Something ) );

memcpy( alt, &setIt, sizeof( funcType ) );
memset( &setIt, 0, sizeof( funcType ) ); // point 1

(*alt)( 15 );
destination->SeeIt( );
auto b = destination->GetIt( );
```

A quick explanation:

Create a new `Something` and call all of it's members to make sure it's working correctly. Then move it to a new location and delete/clear where it used to exist. Also move the function object to a new location and clean up after. Then, using pointer's to the new locations, call the function object and the methods on the object.

The first issue is that everything is moving along smoothly until I `memset` the original location of the function object. If you comment out that line (noted with `// point 1`) you'll notice it does not crash.

This is a little strange to me, but I don't fully understand how function objects are laid out in memory and was hoping for a little light to be shed in that area. I would assume that if I block-copied the entire object to another area and cleared the old space (not deleting it because it's on the stack) that it and all of it's references would be preserved.

The second issue, assuming you've commented out the `memset` line is that "expected results" are not the same as "desired results". I expect that calling `alt` will set `_myNum` on `s` to 15, and it does. But I want to update `alt`'s pointer to `Something` (which I usually refer to as it's `this` pointer) to point to `destination`. How can I achieve that? Can it be done dependably across compilers? I've been worried that, although I could conceivably find where it's stored and update the value, the solution won't be solid because lambda's can be implemented in a variety of ways across compilers and there may be some "magic" at hand.

Any help or insight into these issues is greatly appreciated. If I'm not clear on what's going on, comment and I'll provide more detail where needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `new` and `delete` operators together with `operator=`?  What you're doing isn't idiomatic C++.

Comment: This is rudimentary example of how things work in the memory manager I've been working on. I don't use `new` and `delete` in it for a few reasons, so this is mostly to illustrate the concept.

Comment: What makes you think `memcpy`ing a lambda into an `std::function` is going to work? A lambda can be stored in an `std::function`, that doesn't mean they're the same thing, or layout compatible. In general, there's little chance `memcpy`ing *anything* to/from an `std::function` will produce the desired behavior.

Comment: You can't memcpy setIt into alt and then use it. SetIt has a reference to where s's member variable was in memory. You'd want to call GetSetIt() on the new object (ie: alt) to have a getter/setter for it.

Comment: My bad, I messed up my example. Edit.

Comment: ^^ Shouldn't comments be constructive? I'm just looking for some help here; I get that the gut reaction when someone see's `malloc` or `memset` is to freak out, but it doesn't take away from the fact that this is C++11 code.

Comment: Please use placement new/delete

Comment: Can people please focus on the question at hand rather than mocking the style of code?

Comment: @WilliamCustode The suggestion to use placement new is not *mocking* your code. Your code is broken the way you've presented it, and the only constructive thing that can be said about it is to use placement new to create/copy the `std::function` objects.

Answer (score 3):

`function` is not trivially copyable (3.9p9, 9p6) so you cannot copy it with `memcpy`. Use the [`is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) trait to detect whether a type is trivially copyable.

If you want to "move" an object of a non-trivially copyable type from one location to another, use placement new with its move constructor and perform a destructor call on the previous location:

```
new (*buf) T(std::move(obj));
obj.~T();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use placement new and ensure the setter is taken from the copied object:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// ...

int main() {
    char source[sizeof(Something)];
    char source_setter[sizeof(funcType)];
    Something* src = new (source) Something;
    // Get the setter from the source object.
    funcType* src_setter = new (source_setter) funcType(src->GetSetIt());
    (*src_setter)(0);

    char destination[sizeof(Something)];
    char destination_setter[sizeof(funcType)];
    Something* dst = new (destination) Something(*src);
    // Get the setter from the destination object.
    funcType* dst_setter = new (destination_setter) funcType(dst->GetSetIt());
    (*dst_setter)(1);

    src->SeeIt();
    dst->SeeIt();

    src_setter->~funcType();
    src->~Something();
    dst_setter->~funcType();
    dst->~Something();
}
```